# How refer to the "strands" of algae and their movement in a current?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm referring to the algae attached at the bottom of a river. The one with long "leaves/stands." How are those "extensions" called? And which verb to use to describe their movement with the flow of the rive (I need everyday terminology not scientific one.)

Examine:

> I saw some algae at the bottom of the river. Their [...] were [...] with the current.

Comment: Have you read anything about algae such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algae?  This information seems to be GR.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on a related site.  

Comment: Is this the same as your question from earlier today?

Comment: Perhaps *seaweed*?

Comment: http://quimperhitty.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/img_3918.jpg or http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_ODUGlGhaapI/TB_B0wHbQ4I/AAAAAAAASKg/MxObWxD7wLw/s1600/encrusted+rock-1.JPG http://www.fauna.is/photos/Acrosiphonia_arcta.jpg ?

Comment: Most people tend to think of hair alge as "alge".  If you are talking about hair alge, Biologists refer to the parts as "hair".  In which case, undulating, waving, or any of the other hair related (or even stream related) motions might apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think the leaves of algae would best be called *[fronds](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frond)*:-

> 1. The leaf of a fern.
> 2. A large compound leaf of a palm.
> 3. A leaflike thallus, as of a seaweed or lichen.

As for their movement, perhaps *[wave](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wave)* would be best:-

> :  to float, play, or shake in an air current :  move loosely to and
>   fro :  flutter

although in this case the current would be water.

Comment: There seems to be no reference to algae in the definition you cite.

Comment: @Kris [seaweed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaweed) is algae.

Comment: Ok, http://www.ehow.com/facts_7502915_function-fronds.html

Comment: Is *frond* a commonly used word?

Comment: Frond is commonly used in some contexts, but I don't think is suitable to refer to algae.  I would probably just use the word strands or leaves, as in your question!

Answer (score 1):

If the type of algae you're referring to looks like [this](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/flowers-blue-green-algae-river-wate-12396249.jpg), I would probably talk about *strands* of algae.  You use the word in your question, but it's honestly one of the better options.

You might also use the word *tendrils*, which might not be scientifically accurate, but is easily understandable in context.

In addition to the already mentioned *wave*, they could be described as *undulating*, although that word probably wouldn't be used in informal speech.